# JQuery bind() only tiggered once

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following jquery script that is attached to button elements. At the moment, I'm only testing with one button but the idea is that clicking on any button will read the id of the button that is then used as part of the URL to call back to the web server. The button I'm testing with is on the main page i.e. visible as you arrive on the site. However even the main page (and the button itself) is loaded via an AJAX call! Also the button is part of the #content element that the script itself empties as shown below.

The behaviour I'm seeing:
- If I stay on the main page and click on the button, it works. Then if I navigate back, it doesn't work any more.

- If I arrive on the site and navigate away from the main page and go back, the button won't work again.

The pattern seems to be that the script won't run if the button is ever taken out of the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").bind('click', function(){
          var route = element.attr("id");
          $.ajax(
          {
            type: "GET",
            url: '/' + route,
            dataType: "html",
            async: true,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $( "#content" ).empty();
                $( "#content" ).append( data );
            } 
           }); 
    });
});
```

I'm new to JQuery and AJAX and even though I'm sure it's a trivial issue I haven't been able to find the answer online.

I'm using Chrome and JQuery 2.1.1.

Many thanks

Update: also tried with $('body button').on('click'... as suggested below but getting the same behaviour.

Comment: You add the handlers *to the DOM element*, meaning your `$.bind()` is run once on whatever elements are present against it's selector. Once you remove an element, it's event handlers get removed too. If you want to continue handling that event, re-apply the event handler when you re-add those elements, or use `$.on()` through a parent using the second selector option (as long as the parent is not also removed).

Comment: @JaredFarrish thanks. It makes sense, however I tried changing it to to $('body button').on(click... and getting the same behaviour.

Comment: Use the *second* argument, e.g., `$(document).on('click', 'button', func...)`. Also don't apply handlers to `body`, it is in general a bad idea; use `document` if you must, or preferentially a common parent closer in the DOM to your element (so you don't have unnecessary event management going on).

Comment: @JaredFarrish perfect! Please add this as answer so I can accept it as it fixed the issue! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the handlers to the *DOM element*, meaning your *$.bind()* is run once on whatever elements are present against it's selector. Once you remove an element, it's event handlers get removed too.

If you want to continue handling that event, re-apply the event handler when you re-add those elements, or use `$.on()` through a parent using the second selector option (as long as the parent is not also removed). This is called *event delegation*. (The precursor to `$.on()` was called `$.delegate()`, but was changed for syntactical reasons.)

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', func...)
```

Make sure and use the second argument. Also don't apply handlers to `body`, it is in general a bad idea; use `document` if you must, or preferentially a common parent closer in the DOM to your element (so you don't have unnecessary event management going on).